# How to build and run a docker container on a cradlepoint router?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, network-programming, router

So on Netcloud you can use compose(yaml file) to build and run Docker containers.
The router is connected to Netcloud and it does say it's online, but on Netcloud you can check the last sync error which comes up as:

```
Configuration Rejected
The router rejected the last change.
config.lan At most one of the networks sharing a VLAN interface can have DHCP enabled. However, it is enabled on both Control network and Res network.
```

The error is strange because I factory reset the router, so it does not have the Control and Res network anymore. I am just assuming the problem is the Compose file, it's just using an older error code after saying "config.lan".

A simple compose file works on my laptop but it doesn't work on the cradlepoint router. The router is the IBR1700 which specifically runs Docker containers. I have the files saved on Docker hub but it always shows the error configuration rejected. I have also tried multiple times (this screenshot shows config version 50), so I would be really thankful for help on this.

[image: Updated screenshot of error]

Simple compose file that works on laptop:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3056:3056
    image: username/repository
```

I have tried a number of different variations:

```
version: '3'
services:
  smartresp:
    # Fill out the appropriate registry and image information here...
    image: "username/repository:latest"
    container_name: "res"
    logging:
      driver: json-file
    devices:
      - $EXT_SERIAL
      - $USB_SERIAL
    ports:
      - 3056:3056/tcp
      - 6013:6013/udp
      - 6014:6014/udp
    volumes:
      - 'data:/home/logs'

volumes:
  smartresp-data:
    driver: local
```

Or this (it was created using Compose Builder on Netcloud):

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  smartresDocker:
    network_mode: bridge
    image: 'username/repository:latest'
    entrypoint: setup_docker_buildx.sh
    command: '["python3", "./main.py"]'
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - '3056:3056'
    environment:
      - ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
      - ENV TEST_MODE_NO_PLC 1
      - ENV TEST_MODE_NO_PRINTER 1
      - ENV TEST_MODE_NO_PAGER 1
      - ENV TEST_MODE_NO_MODEM 1
```

None of them work.

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the issue was the Docker Compose code but the main issue was the router not connecting to Netcloud Manager, so it was a configuration issue.
Once connected, it will show container errors if you click on:

**Router -> Containers -> Projects**. The last column is the *Error* column which will show any errors e.g a pulling error, a build compose file error.

The first step to fix the router is to press **Configuration -> Clear**.
The next step is to factory reset the router. If you can login directly to the router, you can factory reset in the System options, but can also factory reset the router by holding the Reset button for at least 30 seconds.

Afterwards, press **Configuration -> Resume Updates**
You will know this has worked if Configuration on the router column is shown as *Synched* (not Suspended or Pending). You may need to keep pressing the refresh button in the top right (it does take time).

Once it has synced you can use a simple Docker Compose file to pull the repository from Docker Hub (note: it must be a public repository).
The Cradlepoint IBR700 router uses the Docker Compose version 3.3

Here is a working sample of some Docker compose code:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3056:3056
    logging:
      driver: json-file
    image: username/repository
```

NOTE: You should have *logging: driver: json-file* because it can be used to find errors when running. This is done by logging into the router and going to **System Control -> Device Options -> Device Console**. Here you can type **container logs test** (where test is the name of the container, and it will list them if the container name is not available).

You must also make sure that the image name in Docker Hub matches the name of the repository you are pushing it to.

Overview of Docker Compose
https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Get started with Docker Compose
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/